# Counting the number of times a value appears in range of cells in another worksheet using a wildcard

Tags: count, excel-formula, wildcard

I have a worksheet that has 13 sheets in it.  The data in the cells could be 8T, 8W, 8AL etc.  I would like to count the number of times any of these occur from say O5:O32 in a separate .xslx worksheet/file, but not as a total for all 13 sheets, but rather each one individually. Normally you would do this with a wildcard (e.g. 8*), although I know wildcards don't exist in excel.

So basically in "worksheet2.xlsx" "sheet1", I want to count how many times anything starting with 8 appears from O5:O32 in "sheet1" of "worksheet1.xlsx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> although I know you wildcards don't exist in excel

Oh they do! Try this:

```
=COUNTIF([Worksheet1.xlsx]Sheet1!O5:O32,"8*")
```

Is there anything in your requirements that this does not achieve?

Comment: That is the exact formula I was using, but noticed that sometimes it does not count correctly.  Not all the time, just some.  I though there was a problem using the *.  Hmmm.  Let me have another look, perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I converted a .pdf to an .xlsx because I think those are the ones I am having problems with

Comment: So what does it count incorrectly? notice it matches anything starting with `8`, including numbers like `80`, `800`, `83` etc. If this is the source of error and you want to exclude these, the formula needs some modification.

Comment: It's not counting the plain 8.  Between O5:O32, I have 3 plain 8's and an 8A.  It's counting the 8A but not the 8's.  Does "8*" not include 8 as well.  I know how to fix that if that is the case, I just thought it would be all inclusive, anything with 8

Comment: Yeah it desn't match it. Try instead `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT([Worksheet1.xlsx]Sheet1!O5:O32, 1) = "8"))`

Comment: That works!!  I was so close using that formula, just had a minor syntax error.  Thanks!!

Comment: @niklas24 glad to know that. :)